# Python graph recursion

Tags: python, recursion

```
d={'a':['b','d'],'b':['c'],'c':['d']}

def path(d,consider,end,route=''):
    if consider==end:

        return route
    else:
        for e in d[consider]:
            print(e)
            route = path(d,e,end,route)
            route=str(e)+route
            print route

            return route
```

`path(d,'a','d')` prints:

```
b
c
d
d
cd
bcd
Out[89]:
'bcd'
```

Why does it not print the second consideration of 'a' i.e 'd'. it outputs the branch for 'b' but does not seem to explore 'd' even though it is supposed to by the for loop.

Comment: is your last `return` indeed inside the `for` loop?

Comment: You have a `return` in your `for` loop. That means your loop will only run one iteration, and then the function is exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use breadth-first search to find the shortest path:

```
import collections
def path(d, consider, end):
  queue = collections.deque([consider])
  seen = []
  flag = False
  while queue:
    val = queue.popleft()
    if val == end:
      return seen
    seen.append(val)
    queue.extend([i for i in d[val] if i not in seen])
  return flag

result = path({'a':['b','d'],'b':['c'],'c':['d']}, 'a', 'd')
result = result if result else []
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you unconditionally `return` the route in the very first iteration of the loop, i.e. after following the first branch, regardless of whether that actually led to `end`. Instead, you have to check whether the `route` returned is `not None` (`None` being implicitly returned after the loop). You also should check whether `consider in d` before starting the loop. Also, you should not overwrite the original value of `route` inside the loop. In fact, the `route` parameter is useless, as it will ever only be `""`.

```
def path(d, consider, end):
    if consider == end:
        return ''
    elif consider in d:
        for e in d[consider]:
            res = path(d, e, end)
            if res is not None:
                return e + res
```

If you want all the routes that lead to `end`, use `yield` instead of `return`. In this case, the condition is not needed, as this will only yield valid paths in the first place, and never `None`, but you need another loop to iterate the different successful paths, if any.

```
def path(d, consider, end):
    if consider == end:
        yield ''
    elif consider in d:
        for e in d[consider]:
            for res in path(d, e, end):
                yield e + res
```

This way, `list(path(d,'a','d'))` results in `['bcd', 'd']`

Note, however, that on a cyclic graph this may lead to an infinite recursion, even if there is a short path to the goal, depending on the layout of the graph. You could counter this by either passing an ever-growing set of already visited nodes in each iteration, or popping visited nodes from the graph `d` itself, or by including a counter of already visited nodes, and stopping if that counter is higher than the number of nodes in the graph.

Comment: This will still stop at the first route found - like it already does - even when there are more than one possible route.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible routes from "a" to "d": the short one ("a"=>"d") given in `d['a'][1]`, and the long one ("a" => "b" => "c" => "d") computed by recursion from `d['a'][0]`.

The problem is that your `path` function only "considers" the first element for a given key:

```
    for e in d[consider]:
        route = path(d,e,end,route)
        route=str(e)+route
        # this return here means we stop at `d[consider][0]`
        # and never checks `d[consider][1:]` 
        return route
```

Actually your function should return a list of all possible routes (instead of the single first possible one) so the caller can select the shortest one (or the longest one or whatever you like)

As a side note, I would not build routes from string concatenations but as lists themselves so there's no ambiguity when someone starts using names with one than more letter as keys in `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the return?

```
def path(d,consider,end,route=''):
    if consider==end:
        return route
    else:
        for e in d[consider]:
            print(e)
            route = path(d, e, end, route)
            route=str(e)+route
            print(route)

        return route
```

Comment: "Move the return?" Yes, but not _there_.

Comment: @tobias_k not there?  Where else?

Comment: @Alfe If you have it just inside the loop, it returns the very first path, and after the loop, it returns the last path, regardless of whether those led to the goal or not.

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah, maybe the algorithm is only called when a solution exists.

Comment: @Alfe But even then, without a check, it will just find _any_ (non-)solution.